# Why isn't my script modifying the 'name' column?

Tags: python

I'm working with data in the following form:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.            
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

And would like to get it to look like this:

```
name    phone   email   website area    degree
Diane Grant Albrecht                    M.S.
Lannister G. Cersei 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com CEP M.A.T.
Argle D. Bargle                 Ed.M.
Sam D. Man  000-000-1111, 111-222-3333  dman123@gmail.com       dman123@gmail.com       Ed.M.
D G Bamf                    M.S.
Amy Tramy Lamy                  Ph.D.
```

You'll notice that the 'name' field can contain a person's name, degree, and area of practice.

(You might also notice that the second two 'Sam D. Man...' entries are missing.  For this question, that's irrelevant. In the next stage I remove duplicates)

So I first run through this 'name' column and try to parse the name column in order to separate out the area of practice (ex: CEP) and the degree (ex: Ph.D.).  I attempt to write these to the created fields 'area' and 'degree' and to save the modified / shortened name to the 'name' field. At the end of this section, ideally, each 'name' field would only contain the person's name.

However, when I run the script, it has no effect on the person's name field. How do I adjust my script to alter the name?

Thanks!

Here's my script that I've commented to help make it easier to digest:

```
# Stores a list of dictionaries, each dictionary containing a person's entry with keys corresponding to variable names (ex: [{'name':'Sam', 'phone':'111-111-1111'...},{}])
myjson = []
# Add fields 'area' and 'degree' to store area of pract and deg earned, which will be parsed from the 'name' field
with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:
     sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
     sheet.fieldnames.append('flag')
     sheet.fieldnames.append('area')
     sheet.fieldnames.append('degree')
     for row in sheet:
        myjson.append(row)
```

At this point, I have a list of dictionaries called 'myjson.' Each dictionary represents an entry into the database. I advance on to looking at the 'name' field:

```
degrees = ['M.A.T.','Ph.D.','MA','J.D.','Ed.M.', 'M.A.', 'M.B.A.', 'Ed.S.', 'M.Div.', 'M.Ed.', 'RN', 'B.S.Ed.', 'M.D.', 'M.S.']

# Parse name element
for row in myjson:

    # check whether the name string has an area of practice by checking if there's a comma separator
    if ',' in row['name']:

        # separate area of practice from name and degree and bind this to var 'area'. If error, area is an empty list
        split_area_nmdeg = row['name'].split(',')
        try:
            row['area'].append(split_area_nmdeg.pop())
        except AttributeError:
            row['area'] = []

        # Split the name and deg by spaces. If there's a deg, it will match with one of elements and will be stored deg list. The deg is removed name_deg list and all that's left is the name.
        split_name_deg = re.split('\s',split_area_nmdeg[0])
        for word in split_name_deg:
            for deg in degrees:
                if deg == word:
                    try:
                        row['degree'].append(split_name_deg.pop())
                    except AttributeError:
                        row['degree'] = []
                row['name'] = ' '.join(split_name_deg)
                print row['name']

    # if the name string does not contain a comma and therefore does not contain an area of practice
    else:
        row['area'] = []
        split_name_deg = re.split('\s',row['name'])
        for word in split_name_deg:
            for deg in degrees:
                try:
                    if deg == word:
                        row['degree'].append(split_name_deg.pop())
                except AttributeError:
                    row['degree'] = []
                row['name'] = ' '.join(split_name_deg)
                print row['name']
```

Check the output:

```
for row in myjson:
    print row
```

Which looks like this:

```
{'website': '', 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'flag': None, 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.got.com', 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '111-222-3333', 'flag': None, 'email': 'cersei@got.com'}
{'website': '', 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'flag': None, 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '000-000-1111', 'flag': None, 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'flag': None, 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '111-222-333', 'flag': None, 'email': '    dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'name': 'D G Bamf M.S.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'flag': None, 'email': ''}
{'website': '', 'name': 'Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'flag': None, 'email': ''}
first_row {'website': '', 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'degree': [], 'area': [], 'phone': '', 'email': ''}
```

Comment: You might want to investigate the logging and pdb modules: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and then you can step through. Put it in suspect areas of your code and it will help you figure out what's happening.

Comment: Don't you think it's time to learn the regex tools ?

Comment: Parsing using regex is pretty involved when there are so many variations in how degrees can be arranged, in the number of entries for the name (title, middle initial / name, etc.)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your method of determining whether the degree is in the name is working. Unfortunately I couldn't get a full test working because when I pasted your sample data into a text file I don't think the tabs have been maintained correctly, so reading the data into a dictionary does not work. However, using the output shown from your print rows above I have created a dictionary and running the code below on this seems to work to find the degrees and split them out into a separate field:

```
for row in myjson:
    for d in degrees:
        if d in row['name']:
            row['degree'] = d
            row['name'] = row['name'][:row['name'].find(d)]
```

Comment: Trying now, thx for posting and will get back to you with results.

Comment: ah, just realised that I have not allowed for multiple degrees in the above. I will edit this shortly with a correction.

Comment: I've actually only borrowed the 'in' syntax from this which worked nice. What helped my code was initializing degree and area as empty lists and then appending. I should be able to use append to add multiple degrees.

Comment: okay, that's great. If any problems please provide an example of what the dictionary looks like before the processing and I can investigate further.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the above an example? The list of dictionaries at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I was after an example that not been modified by your loop through the data. For example Lannister G. Cersei has the M.A.T. but not the CEP after it. Also, I don't think CEP is in your list of degrees.